# Schedule email with attachment with Automator

Tags: email, automator, attachments, macos

I'm having issues when trying to add an attachment to a scheduled Email in Automator.

If I use `Add Attachment to Front Message` it opens my predefined message and adds the file but as soon as I add `Send Outgoing Messages` the message is sent without the attachment.

I execute this app with a calendar event.

[image: This is my workflow]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. The correct order of actions in Automator:
`Get Specified Finder items` (Here you can add attachments, can be left empty) 
 `New Mail Message` (Receiver, Subject, Message etc) 
 `Send Outgoing Message`

Use the .app format and make sure Automator has "Full Disc Access" otherwise a prompt will pop up wich you will have to manually approve. For some reason it would still need a manual confirmation when trying to use Desktop items.
[image: The workflow]